# QUERY Specific column based on current date in google sheets

Tags: date, select, google-sheets

Please my sample sheet below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDBqzwsyakyP3RGWAdNKs76Ia7JOGFwjIl_czREU0s0/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to know if I can query / filter a table to show someone's schedule based on the current date (Please see cell A25), I want to be able to have that table update based on the current date. Please advise. Thank you in advance, I appreciate all the help that I am getting from this group.

Comment: Sorry for the spam, that is on the 'combined' tab. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

try simple:

```
=FILTER(B2:9, B1:1=B25)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my inquiries. I'm gonna go ahead and explore more perhaps will ask again if get into a bump 